# Jasper Report Module on OpenERP 7

Tags: python, jasper-reports, odoo

I was trying to install Jasper Report module for OpenERP 7

I got them Syleam mdule from here
https://github.com/syleam/openerp-jasperserver

and  download OpenERP 7 from here
http://nightly.openerp.com/7.0/nightly/src/

I already install httplib2, pyPdf and python-dime that was required for this module.But when i try to install the module i got this error

> OpenERP Server Error
>
> Client Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
>       response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1132, in
>   call_button
>       action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1120, in
>   _call_kw
>       return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
>       result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args,
>   kw)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in
>   proxy_method
>       result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
>       raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)
>
> Server Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
>       return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
>       result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line
>   626, in dispatch
>       res = fn(db, uid, *params)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
>       return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
>       return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
>       res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
>       return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 426, in
>   button_immediate_install
>       return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)   File
>   "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 477, in
>   _button_immediate_function
>       _, pool = pooler.restart_pool(cr.dbname, update_module=True)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/pooler.py", line 39, in restart_pool
>       registry = RegistryManager.new(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/modules/registry.py",
>   line 233, in new
>       openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/modules/loading.py",
>   line 354, in load_modules
>       loaded_modules, update_module)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 256, in
>   load_marked_modules
>       loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules,
>   perform_checks=perform_checks)   File
>   "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 188, in
>   load_module_graph
>       load_data(module_name, idref, mode)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 76, in 
>       load_data = lambda *args: _load_data(cr, *args, kind='data')   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 124, in
>   _load_data
>       tools.convert_xml_import(cr, module_name, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/tools/convert.py",
>   line 959, in convert_xml_import
>       obj.parse(doc.getroot())   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 852, in parse
>       self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 812, in _tag_record
>       f_val = _eval_xml(self,field, self.pool, cr, self.uid, self.idref)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 154, in _eval_xml
>       for n in node]), idref)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 148, in _process
>       idref[id]=self.id_get(cr, id)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 829, in id_get
>       res = self.model_id_get(cr, id_str)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 838, in model_id_get
>       return model_data_obj.get_object_reference(cr, self.uid, mod, id_str)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 18, in
>   lookup
>       r = self.lookup(self2, cr, *args)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 46, in lookup
>       value = d[key] = self.method(self2, cr, *args)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 876, in
>   get_object_reference
>       data_id = self._get_id(cr, uid, module, xml_id)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 18, in lookup
>       r = self.lookup(self2, cr, *args)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 46, in lookup
>       value = d[key] = self.method(self2, cr, *args)   File "/opt/openerp-7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 869, in
>   _get_id
>       raise ValueError('No such external ID currently defined in the system: %s.%s' % (module, xml_id)) ValueError: No such external ID
>   currently defined in the system:
>   jasper_server.load_jrxml_file_wizard_action

Anyone can help me what happen and how to solve that ?

oh and 1 more when i try to open module jasper_server_wizard_sample i got an error too (open not install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently an open [Pull Request](https://github.com/syleam/openerp-jasperserver/pull/9) to " install module without error about missing reference".

Maybe it's a bug and that PR fixes it.

Comment: Ah . . you right. Just to change order of loaded view (move 'wizard/load_file_view.xml' from last loaded list to third list) and its succesfully installed. thanks Daniel